# Disabling backref in secondary multibib bibliography with natbib

Tags: natbib, subdividing, back-referencing, multibib

I am finalising my PhD thesis that I have composed with LaTeX.

I have a section in which I list my own publications and the whole list of references at the very end of the document. This list is rather long and I decided to include back references to ease the reading. I used a combination of `natbib`, `multibib` and `backref`. Unfortunately, this enabled them on the secondary bibliography containing my own publications as well.

How am I supposed to disable back references for publications and enables them for the bibliography? I think I burnt my brain and I can not find a solution on my own! Anyway, please find attached a minimal working example.

*Bonus question:* I included my own works in `publications.bib` and I repeated them in `biblio,bib` (the main bibliography DB) adding a `copy` suffix to their keys, not to mess with them.
Is there a more clever way than the one I pursued to cite them and list them in the `Publications` paragraph of the thesis, and list them in the main bibliography with all the back references but those in the `Publications` paragraph?

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{publications}{\null}

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand{\backrefnotcitedstring}{\relax} %(Not cited.)
\newcommand{\backrefcitedsinglestring}[1]{\\\textsmaller{(Cited on page~#1)}}
\newcommand{\backrefcitedmultistring}[1]{\\\textsmaller{(Cited on pages~#1)}}
\renewcommand{\backreftwosep}{ and~} % separate 2 pages
\renewcommand{\backreflastsep}{, and~} % separate last of longer list
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}  % disable standard
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{\ifcase #1 \backrefnotcitedstring \or \backrefcitedsinglestring{#2} \else \backrefcitedmultistring{#2} \fi}

\begin{document}
    \chapter*{Publications}
    Some ideas and figures have previously and partially appeared in \citep{me2012a,me2012b}.
    \begingroup     
        \let\clearpage\relax    
        \vspace{-6ex}
        \nocitepublications{*}
        \bibliographystylepublications{abbrvnat}
        \bibliographypublications{publications}
    \endgroup

    \chapter{Introduction} 
    In this thesis I take some of the concepts that I introduced in \citep{me2012acopy,me2012bcopy} and I quote others proposed in \citep{he2011,she2011,them2011}.

    \appendix   
    \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
    \bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

**publications.bib**

```
@article {me2012a,
  author = {Me, I},
  title = {Title 1},
  journal = {A Journal},
  journaltitle = {A Journal},
  year = {2012}
}

@article {me2012b,
  author = {Me, I},
  title = {Title 2},
  journal = {A Journal},
  journaltitle = {A Journal},
  year = {2012}
}
```

**biblio.bib**

```
@article {me2012acopy,
  author = {Me, I},
  title = {Title 1},
  journal = {A Journal},
  journaltitle = {A Journal},
  year = {2012}
}

@article {me2012bcopy,
  author = {Me, I},
  title = {Title 2},
  journal = {A Journal},
  journaltitle = {A Journal},
  year = {2012}
}

@article {he2011,
  author = {He, Author},
  title = {Title He},
  journal = {A Journal},
  journaltitle = {A Journal},
  year = {2011}
}

@article {she2011,
  author = {She, Author},
  title = {Title She},
  journal = {A Journal},
  journaltitle = {A Journal},
  year = {2011}
}

@article {them2011,
  author = {Them, Authors},
  title = {Title Them},
  journal = {A Journal},
  journaltitle = {A Journal},
  year = {2011}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! Weird, it solves the problem in the minimal example, but not the whole thesis... In fact it is the first thing I tried myself! I'll investigate the other things that I stripped from the project to get the MWE. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh dear! My fault! I simply made a typo (`\backrefS*` instead of `\backref*`) and I was too tired to notice it... Thanks so much and sorry for wasting everybody's time! :-P

Comment: You don't need to copy all the entries from `publications.bib`, `\bibliography{biblio,publications}` in the appendix should suffice.

Comment: @cyberSingularity Based on the feedback, your comment is the answer here, at least for the MWE. Could you convert to an answer?

Answer (score 1):

For your main question about disabling the back references for the "publications" bibliography but enabling them for the main bibliography, you can simply set the backref macros to do nothing inside the TeX group for the first bibliography (these are the macros `\backrefcitedsinglestring` and `\backrefcitedmultistring`):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{publications}{\null}

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{relsize}

\newcommand{\backrefnotcitedstring}{\relax} %(Not cited.)
\newcommand{\backrefcitedsinglestring}[1]{\\\textsmaller{(Cited on page~#1)}}
\newcommand{\backrefcitedmultistring}[1]{\\\textsmaller{(Cited on pages~#1)}}
\renewcommand{\backreftwosep}{ and~} % separate 2 pages
\renewcommand{\backreflastsep}{, and~} % separate last of longer list
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}  % disable standard
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{\ifcase #1 \backrefnotcitedstring \or \backrefcitedsinglestring{#2} \else \backrefcitedmultistring{#2} \fi}

\begin{document}
    \chapter*{Publications}
    Some ideas and figures have previously and partially appeared in \citeppublications{me2012a,me2012b}.
    \begingroup
        % disable backref here
        \renewcommand{\backrefcitedsinglestring}[1]{}%
        \renewcommand{\backrefcitedmultistring}[1]{}%
        % end changes added by cyberSingularity
        \let\clearpage\relax
        \vspace{-6ex}
        \nocitepublications{*}
        \bibliographystylepublications{abbrvnat}
        \bibliographypublications{publications}
    \endgroup

    \chapter{Introduction} 
    In this thesis I take some of the concepts that I introduced in \citep{me2012acopy,me2012bcopy} and I quote others proposed in \citep{he2011,she2011,them2011}.

    \appendix
    \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
    \bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

(You were also missing the `relsize` package in your MWE.)

Your "bonus question" is sufficiently different that it warrants its own question with an appropriate title.